# Rigorous Explanation of Internal Direct Sum Criterion

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

In "Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, 3rd edition", on page 21 "internal direct sum", or direct sum as the author uses, is defined as such:

Let $U_1, U_1,...,U_m$ be subspaces of $V$ vector space over field $F$, if any $v\in V$ can be written **uniquely** as a sum of $u_1+u_2+...+u_m$ where each $u_i\in U_i$, then the sum ($U_1+U_2+...+U_m$) is **internal direct sum**.   **[1]**

On page 23 following this definition, a condition to check whether or not a sum of subspaces is internal direct is stated as follows:

A direct sum is internal direct sum if and only if the only way to write $0$ vector as the sum of $u_1+u_2+...+u_m$ where each $u_i\in U_i$ is equal to $0$.   **[2]**

**Question (1):** How do we infer **[2]** from **[1]**?

**Question (2):** Why does checking whether or not $0$ vector can be uniquely written as the sum of $u_1+u_2+...+u_m$ where each $u_i=0$ suffice to say that the sum is internal direct sum? In other words, why is it not possible to be able to write $0$ vector uniquely while other vectors $v\neq 0$ are not writable uniquely, or vice versa?

I checked out many books about Linear Algebra as to a rigorous explanation for that, but I could not find anything satisfactory. Being these said, what I look for is some eloquent explanation to all these questions I stated above.

Comment: Your question 1 and question 2 are actually the same question. Just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core idea is that if you have two different ways to decompose the same vector
$$
u_1 + \cdots + u_m = v_1 + \cdots + v_m
$$
(where $u_i, v_i\in U_i$) then the zero vector can be decomposed as
$$
0 = (u_1 - v_1) + (u_2  -v_2) + \cdots + (u_m - v_m)
$$
and since the two original decompositions were different, not all these terms can cancel, and we have found a second way to decompose the $0$ vector.

So if there is *some* vector which can be decomposed in two different ways, then the $0$ vector can be decomposed in two different ways. Contrapositively, if the $0$ vector can only be decomposed as $0 = u_1 +\cdots + u_m$ with $u_1 = \cdots = u_m = 0$, then any other vector also only has one deomposition.